# How to seperate 2 LinearLayouts with weight property from parent LinearLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have a layout xml file which contains a LinearLayout with 2 child LinearLayouts in it.
I want to seperate the childs so I will have them in 2 layout xml files, then define the parent LinearLayout in Kotlin code and add the childs to it. Please correct me if this is the right way to do it.

The problem is that the first LinearLayout child as a weight of 0.2 and the second child has 0.8 weight. So when I add them to the parent LinearLayout which is defined in Kotlin, it returns an empty item.

This is how I defined the parent LinearLayout in Kotlin:

```
val podView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.first_item, parent, false)
val podViewDate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.second_item, parent, false)
val podViewWrapper = LinearLayout(parent.context)
val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
podViewWrapper.layoutParams = params
podViewWrapper.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
podViewWrapper.addView(podViewDate)
podViewWrapper.addView(podView)
podViewWrapper.setDividerPadding(30)
```

> This is the file I want to seperate - profile_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sun"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/numberBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberBarText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use relations of integers for weights... You obviously want one to be a fourth of the other, so give it the weight `1` and the other a weight of `4`. It might be necessary to define the orientation of the parent, too.

Comment: @deHaar Still not showing anything, I have changed the weights as you said, added the code of my parent LL in the question

Comment: You need to set layout params of your child layouts too. In your code I can see settings `layoutParams` for parent only.

Comment: `podView` and `podViewDate` need `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ??)` set on them, where `??` is the weight for each (which is perfectly fine as a decimal). `podViewWrapper` will only have `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` if it itself is inside another `LinearLayout`. You also need to add `podViewWrapper` to some on-screen `ViewGroup` before you will see it, but you've not shown how or where that's happening, so we can't tell if there's a problem there. Btw, `LinearLayout`s are horizontal by default, so you don't really need to explicitly set that.

Comment: Mike M. and Ircover, Thanks for the help my dudes, it is now working :)

Answer (score 0):

You parent layout not have any orientation so add orientation

your parent layout should be look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="12dp"
>
```

if you want your child view side by side then set orientation

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Comment: I want this parent layout to be extracted from xml and to define it programatically, then add the 2 seperated LinearLayout childs to it in code

Comment: @Rondev You will probably have to write something like `podViewWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);`

Comment: You have give `orientation` to your layout .

Comment: Yes, I did it, still not showing my items, this is how you write it in Kotlin:
`podViewWrapper.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL`

Comment: I might found the problem you are creating `podViewWrapper ` linearlayout dynamically and added view to that but add `podViewWrapper ` to the view which presented in your xml.

Comment: @frankenstein But I want `podViewWrapper` to be the parent, So I can safely delete `profile_item.xml` and the LinearLayout will be defined in programatically.

Comment: you have add your `programatic` view in your static view which available on your xml view otherwise view  will won't visible.